# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.map is not a function (React using axios getting data from ASP.NET API)

Tags: c#, reactjs, axios, api-design

I've created an API using ASP.NET, and I've got a Website running React. I'm wanting to display the data retrieve with a get request from the API to React using Axios. The website has an authentication method using two cookies. I can get the Axios to get data from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users, but when i use the same bit of code, then I get the error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.map is not a function.

I've tried as mentioned above to use a placeholder, and that works fine, but can't seem to get thedata from my API, which leads me to believe that the problem lies in the cookies. I've also tried a few Google searches, which returned that I should include withCredentials: true, but that doesn't do the trick.

Here is the function from my API:

```
public JsonResult YearlyManagersJSON(int year = 0)
{
    if (year < 2000 || year > DateTime.Today.Year)
        year = DateTime.Today.Year;

    var startDate = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
    var endDate = new DateTime(year + 1, 1, 1);

    var bonds = this.getOverviewData(ReportType.BONDS, startDate, endDate);
    var bondsSum = bonds.Sum(m => m.Aggregate);

    var viewData = new TopLeadManagerViewData
        {
            Title = String.Format("Top Managers in {0}", startDate.Year),
            Currency = SiteHelper.getCurrencyToUse(),
            Bonds = Enumerable.Select(bonds, m => new ManagerSummary()
                {
                    NumberOfIssues = (int)m.Aggregate2,
                    TotalAmount = m.Aggregate * 1000000,
                    Name = m.Group.ToString(),
                    Share = 100.0m * m.Aggregate / bondsSum
                }),
        };

        return this.Json(viewData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This returns a JSON, which i have checked using Postman. Then i try to access the data using axios.

```
state = {
    yearlyBonds: []
}

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(
        'http://localhost/Stamdata.Web/LeagueTable/YearlyManagersJSON',
        { withCredentials: true }
    )
    .then(res => {
        const yearlyBonds = res.data;
        this.setState({ yearlyBonds });
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        // Tags removed for simplicity
        <ListTable data={this.state.yearlyBonds.Bonds} />
```

The data is then passed down into the component

```
function ListTable(props) {
        const { classes, header, data } = props;
        return(
            // Tags removed for simplicity
                        <TableBody>
                            {data.map((x, i) => {
                                return(
                                    <TableRow key={i}>
                                        <TableCell scope="row">{x.Name}</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell scope="row">{x.TotalAmount}</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell scope="row">{x.Share}</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell scope="row">{x.NumberOfIssues}</TableCell>
                                    </TableRow>
                                )
                            })}
                        </TableBody>
```

So, this returns the error

> "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.map is not a function", which I would like to have display the data retrieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial state is,

```
yearlyBonds: []
```

When component first renders it takes initial state. Initially you have empty array. So iteration over empty array giving you the error.

You can conditionally add your component like,

```
{ this.state.yearlyBonds.Bonds && <ListTable data={this.state.yearlyBonds.Bonds} />}
```

Comment: Thank you for the if statement, but what i'm really looking for is why it is returning undefined

Comment: What is undefined?

Comment: Omg, i'm such an idiot :/ got so lost in my own code that the solution you made didn't work because i placed the code in the ListTable component file instead of in the main file. Thank you so much for making my day better, instead of me ripping my hair out

Answer (score 0):

> Note that, `componentDidMount` gets called after 1st render (when component mounts into DOM).

You have following workflow for the component -

1. During the 1st render, you have a state -

   state = {
       yearlyBonds: []
   }

   In the render function, you want to pass `Bonds` key data which doesn't exist in your initial state until API call is made and state has `Bonds` data.
2. Since `this.state.yearlyBonds.Bonds` is undefined during initial render, you can't call `map` method on `undefined` object. **That is why you're seeing that error**.

> Now to fix this, there are quite a few methods:

**Method #1 (Simplest):**

Update your state like this -

```
state = {
    yearlyBonds: {
       bonds: []
    }
}
```

Your render would work without any additional changes.

**Method #2 (Moderate):**

Update your function to accept de-structured props with default value for `data`

```
function ListTable({ classes, header, data=[] }) {
// rest of the code goes here
```

**Method #3: (The right approach for API calls):**

Add a `isLoading` flag in your component state. We will use this to show a fallback 'Loading ...' UI until we have data from the API.

```
state = {
    yearlyBonds: [],
    isLoading: false,
}
```

Before API call is made, update your state with 'isLoading' set to true.

```
componentDidMount() {
    // update state
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    axios.get(
        'http://localhost/Stamdata.Web/LeagueTable/YearlyManagersJSON',
        { withCredentials: true }
    )
    .then(res => {
        const yearlyBonds = res.data;
        // set isLoading to false, as data is received
        this.setState({ yearlyBonds, isLoading: false });
    })
}
```

Finally in the render method, read `isLoading` state and render a fallback.

```
// rest of the code

render() {
     if (this.state.isLoading) {
        return <div> Loading ... </div>;

    // when data is available
    return (
        // Tags removed for simplicity
        <ListTable data={this.state.yearlyBonds.Bonds} />
```

Comment: the third method seems the most logical, and best practice, but it runs the loading for a second or two, then crashes again. Even if I try to run the this.state.yearlyBonds.map() in the main file and ask for x.Title(which is another json parameter), then it still crashes with "TypeError: this.state.yearlyBonds.map is not a function". Could this be caused by that the cookies aren't sent with the request?

Comment: I don't think so. edit - update the is loading default from false to true and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you are iterating over an empty array.